# apply a numeric offset to each element in a bash array

Tags: arrays, bash

I would like to take the user's input and decrement each value taken in by one.  For example, if the user provides:

> ```
> 0 1 6 8
> ```

I would like to change this to:

> -1 0 5 7

My code looks like this, but doesn't seem to work:

```
echo 'Please enter numbers:'
read numbers
IFS=' '
numarray=($numbers)
for i in "${numarry[@]}"
do
     (( numarray[i]-- )) 
done
echo ${numarray[@]}
```

But the code doesnt seem to work.  Any ideas?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work as you expect, because `for i in ${numarray[@]}` iterates over the elements of the array with `$i` being the actual elements, whereas `(( numarray[i]-- ))` expects `$i` to be the *index* of the array elements. Try this:

```
echo 'Please enter numbers:'
read numbers
IFS=' '
numarray=($numbers)
numarray=($numbers)
for i in $(seq 1 ${#numarry[@]}); do
  (( numarray[i-1]-- )) 
done
echo ${numarray[@]}
```